# How do I simultaneous record the old value and new value with a trigger in an update table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger the simultaneously records the new and old value of MSRP on an update. I thought I had my code right but I get an 1136 error column count doesn't match.

code I have now:

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger prod_upd_old
after update on products
for each row
    BEGIN
        insert into audit_table(productCode, productName, productline, MSRP, last_update, rowValue)
        Values(old.productCode, old.productName, old.productLine, old,MSRP, now(), 'before update');
    END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
create trigger prod_upd_new
after update on products
for each row
follows prod_upd_old
BEGIN
        insert into audit_table(productCode, productName, productline, MSRP, last_update, rowValue)
        values(new.productCode, new.productName, new.productLine, new.MSRP, now(), 'after update');
    END $$
DELIMITER ;

update products set MSRP = '147.50' where productCode = 'S10_4962';
```

Comment: You have a `,` instead of `.` in `old.productLine, old,MSRP, now(), 'before update'` between `old` and `MSRP`. Also, you could do both inserts in the same trigger, with a single insert

Comment: ... and `last_update` may be set to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and excluded from UPDATE queries at all.

Comment: Thank you! @Pepper and Akina